# trigger to animate svg

Tags: javascript, svg, svelte

I tried to animate svg `<line>` with `<animate>`, but I can't start the animation with a click event or some condition change. I'm confused how to bind the `begin` attribute with condition/events.

```
<script>
let sparkCond = false
// this function are not doing anythin because I don't bind the condition to anything
function spark() {
    sparkCond = true
}
</script>
<svg>
{#each Array(8) as _,i}
    <g transform="translate(150 150)">
        <line
            class="spark"
            x1={0}
            y1={20}
            x2={0}
            y2={50}
            transform ="rotate({i*45})"
        >
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="0" to="50" begin="0s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze"/>
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="0" to="50" begin="0.2s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze"/>
        <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="0.4s" dur="0.1s" fill="freeze"/>
        </line>
    </g>

{/each}
    
</svg>
<br>
<button on:click={spark}>Click</button>

<style>
    svg {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        border:solid;
    }
    .spark {
        stroke:green;
        stroke-width:5;
        stroke-linecap:round;
    }
</style>
```

link: https://svelte.dev/repl/8f5bae9d183e4268aa1d9b4d91633f9a?version=4.1.1

I use svelte repl, but not mandatory to use svelte directive or features, native javascript is ok.

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/restart

Comment: Break up your challenge in sub tasks; once you learn how to animate one line you can learn how to animate them all. It also helps us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest binding is to reference the button directly in the [`begin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin) attribute. For this, the button **must** have an id:

```
<button id="sparkler">Click</button>
```

Then, use the form `<id>.<event>` to reference the button click:

```
<animate attributeName="y2"
         from="0" to="50"
         begin="sparkler.click" dur="0.2s"
         fill="freeze"/>
```

You can add a time offset:

```
<animate attributeName="y1"
         from="0" to="50"
         begin="sparkler.click+0.2s" dur="0.2s"
         fill="freeze"/>
```

Compare [this MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin#event_example).

If you want to start an animation from Javascript, set the `begin` attribute to `indefinite`. You need a reference to the `<animate>` element, so best give it an id:

*(Since you are defining these animations in a loop, remember that ids must be unique!)*

```
<animate id="sparkle1" attributeName="y2"
         from="0" to="50"
         begin="indefinite" dur="0.2s"
         fill="freeze"/>
<animate id="sparkle2" attributeName="y1"
         from="0" to="50"
         begin=indefinite" dur="0.2s"
         fill="freeze"/>
```

Call the `.beginElement()` method to start the animation:

```
const sparkle1 = document.getElementById('sparkle1');

sparkle1.beginElement();
```

For time offsets, use `.beginElementAt()`, with the offset time in seconds:

```
const sparkle1 = document.getElementById('sparkle2');

sparkle1.beginElementAt(0.2);
```